# If a time-series achieves max-likelihood at GARCH(1,1), would EGARCH, or other GARCH variations achieve global maximum likelihood at p=1, q=1?

Tags: optimization, model-selection, likelihood, garch, lags

If I find that a time-series fits GARCH(1,1), would EGARCH, or other GARCH variations still be X-GARCH(1,1)?

Comment: Your title question does not exactly match the question in the body. I have answered the title question. If you want to ask the question in the body, consider opening a new thread. However, it lacks some detail, so it would be good to make it a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Maximized likelihood increases with model complexity, so it cannot be achieved at lag order (1,1). The maximized likelihood of a (1,2) model will in all likelihood be higher, and it will definitely not be lower. In other words, maximized likelihood is a monotonically nondecreasing function of the "ARCH lag" order and also of the "GARCH lag" order. This holds regardless of whether we look at vanilla GARCH, EGARCH or another variation of GARCH.

Comment: The title question does not exactly match the question in the body. I have answered the former question, as the latter one lacks detail.